# Thinktecture IdentityServer V3 without Sign in page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, openid, thinktecture

I am spiking a solution with Thinktecture IdentityServer V3. The setup of the project is an Asp.net MVC 5 site which uses forms authentication to authenticate the user, we also have a number of web api sites which are hosted seperately.

I would like to use IdentityServer to SSO into the web api sites. this is an internal solution and would like to somehow programatically login to the identity server instead of been shown the login screen.

Is this possible?

Many thanks

Comment: You could write an userService and protect the identityServer with Windows auth. It might be possible to get an matching owin security component for that.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link. 
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/831.
You can sign in as resource owner, but SSO won't be possible.
We can always customize the login page provided on IdentityServer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I really needed SSO.